# Getting value of iteration from the tLoop component (While Loop)

Tags: talend

Is it possible to get value of iteration from a tLoop component if it is in WHILE LOOP configuration? Understand that for FOR LOOP I can get the value using "tLoop_1_CURRENT_VALUE". Can this be achieved if the tLoop component is in WHILE LOOP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get current iteration value in either case of FOR LOOP or WHILE LOOP by using:

```
(Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION")
```